# mySQL connection not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am fairly new to SQL and I am trying to write code to insert information from a messages form.  Here is the SQL code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); 
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) VALUES ( '$name' , '$email' , '$message' )";


if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else {
echo "<html><script language='JavaScript'> alert('Thank you for your submission.'),window.location = 'home'</script></html>";
}
```

This code returns "Error: " that I interpreted as it thinking there is an error, but there isn't any errors.  The connection variables in mysqli_connect are all correct, but I am unsure if I am using the mysqli_real_escape_string correctly and even the $sql statement, because this code also doesn't insert anything into my database.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`. Fix that and then look into prepared statements.

Comment: @AlexTartan i changed it, and I still get "Error:"

Comment: You are not passing $con into mysqli_query()

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone how would I do that?

Comment: You are already doing it with your `mysqli_real_escape_string()` calls...

Comment: ...you have an answer telling you how... and you always have http://php.net if you're ever unsure about some php-function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry I just refreshed

Comment: @Will did my answer work for you in the end?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone yes thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) documentation, if you are using the procedural notation you need to include your mysqli link:

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

This would suggest you need to pass in `$con` to `mysqli_query()` as you have with your other function calls as below:

`mysqli_query($con, $sql)`

Also, please look up and read about parametrization as your code as it is should not be used on a live site as you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and learn how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query this way

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

mysqli_query requires the link to your db connection which is "$con"